# sorting a dictionary python values descending, but keys ascending

Tags: python

I want to get a sorted list of keys from  a dictionary in python (My dictionary is of int to int mapping). I want the values to be sorted in ascending. But in case of collision (same value), I want the keys to be sorted by the numeric value of the key. The following piece of code does that

```
key=lambda x: (dict[x],x)
```

However, I want the ordering of the values in descending and ordering of the keys (only in case of collision) to be descending.  I can apply the reverse parameter, but that will work on both key and its value in the same way.

Is there any way to do it separately?

Example

```
>>> my_dict = {1:5, 2:4, 3:5, 26:3, 5:2, 6:4, 8:3}
>>> my_dict
{1: 5, 2: 4, 3: 5, 5: 2, 6: 4, 8: 3, 26: 3}
>>> sorted_list = sorted(my_dict, key=my_dict.get)
>>> print sorted_list
[5, 8, 26, 2, 6, 1, 3]
```

I want the output to be 
    [5, 26, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1]

Comment: If you sort keys one way and values another way, they will no longer map to each other. Do you have an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a few options:

```
>>> my_dict = {1:5, 2:4, 3:5, 26:3, 5:2, 6:4, 8:3}
>>> sorted(my_dict, key=lambda x: (my_dict[x], -x))
[5, 26, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1]
>>> sorted(sorted(my_dict)[::-1], key=my_dict.get)
[5, 26, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1]
>>> sorted(sorted(my_dict, reverse=True), key=my_dict.get)
[5, 26, 8, 6, 2, 3, 1]
```

The first depends upon the keys being numerical (or at least something which you can negate like this), which is less general than the last two, which use only the fact that the sort is stable.

Comment: If you're sorting inside a loop, you'll likely be better off in terms of performance with an ordered dictionary like a treap or red-black tree.  The treap module I wrote allows you to traverse the keys of a treap in order or in reverse order.  http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/treap/  You might be better off reversing what you consider a value, and what you consider a key, but that's specific to your problem so you know about that better than I do.